# Angular/TypeScript: Write code in Subscription

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using Angular (4) and need help to handle asynchronous data:

Below you can see the method connect(). The first command subscribes an Observable of my service. The following lines need to be in this subscription, too. But I don't know how. The method shall return the result of the method getSortedData() as an Observable.

**my-item-component**

```
   //...
    items: Item[];
    //...
    connect(): Observable<Item[]> {
            this.myItemService.getItem().subscribe(response => {
                this.items = response;
            });
            const displayDataChanges = [
                this.myItemService.getItem(),
                this.sort.sortChange,
            ];
            return Observable.merge(...displayDataChanges).map(() => {
                return this.getSortedData(this.items);
            });
        }
    //..
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not read mutable state inside an operator. When they change, the observable won't know and won't run your code again.

So I removed usage of `this.items`, and I'm passing a `sort` parameter to `getSortedData()`.

```js
connect(): Observable<Item[]> {
  const displayDataChanges = [
    this.myItemService.getItem(),
    this.sort.sortChange,
  ];
  return Observable.combineLatest(...displayDataChanges).map(([items, sort]) => {
    return this.getSortedData(items, sort);
  });
}
```

Instead of `merge()`, I call `combineLatest()` which will run the following operators every time any of the observables change, with the latest values from each.

Comment: Cool thanks, but I don't receive my data anymore. Also combineDate does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'. Do you have any idea?

Comment: And my sort is an '@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;' so I would like to youse this.sort in my getSortedData method direct. Is that possible?

Comment: Which combineDate?!

Comment: Sorry, I meant combineLatest.

Comment: import 'rxjs/Observable/add/combineLatest' once in the project

Comment: Given sort is a simple data, no need for combineLatest not merge just map.

Comment: I already imported combineLatest. But sometimes Visual Studio seems to underline it falsely. I don't want to pass the sort variable. I would like to use this.sort in my getSortedData() method. Is that possible?